# how to make listview height take all available space on the screen

Tags: android, listview

How do I make listview height take all available space on screen, even if there is only one item on the list that is 100dpi tall?

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the width and height of the ListView like this :

```
<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `match_parent` as width and height, and also make sure your background image (if you're using one) is not limiting the height. In that case, if your bg image is larger, the height will go higher and same if smaller. If that's the case, then you should move your background to a parent view like a `FrameLayout` or a `LinearLayout`